Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price') - React
I have an application in react being developed and I have the following error when the application tries to execute a method

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')
at getTotalCartAmount (StoreContext.jsx:33:47)

const getTotalCartAmount = () => {
    let totalAmount = 0;
    for (const item in cartItems) {
        if (cartItems[item] > 0) {
            let itemInfo = product_list.find((product) => product.id === item);
            totalAmount += itemInfo.price * cartItems[item];
        }
    }
    return totalAmount;
};

I believe it is a synchronization problem, but I can't understand where the method should synchronize

Your issue means that find() isn't finding the item - so no product id matches the item you're looking for. This could be because the types are different or the values are different.

Array#find is not guaranteed to return an item in the array. If there is no match, it will return undefined. Make sure you check itemInfo is not undefined before you access it.

I printed if cartItems and productList and I have values.

That doesn't guarantee that there is a matching entry in the product list for every cart item.

and what could be a possible solution?

You need to debug your code. For instance, what is item? Is it a product id as the code assumes?
